# Django js variable issue

Tags: javascript, django

How I can solve my problem?

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="demo">
            <p>{% verbatim %}{{message}}{% endverbatim %}</p>
        </div>

        <script>
            var demo = new Vue({
                el: '#demo',
                data: {
                    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Works without any problems, but:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% load static %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'index/script.js'%}"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="demo">
        <p>{% verbatim %}{{message}}{% endverbatim %}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Browser show "{{message}}". 
Can you help me? I have problem with .js file including.

JS file: 
     var demo = new Vue({
                    el: '#demo',
                    data: {
                        message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
                    }
                })

Comment: sorry.  why do you have {% verbatim %}?

Comment: [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim)
You need to escape the braces with this tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initialize `Vue` the DOM is not loaded yet.
Try to move your script to the end of `body`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    {% load static %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="demo">
        <p>{% verbatim %}{{message}}{% endverbatim %}</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'index/script.js'%}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think about it few hours... You solve my problem in in moment. Thanks a lot!